# php выражение с ~

Tags: php, php5

Почему:

```
php -r "echo ~5-5";
```

выводит: -11?

И что означает такой знак: ~ ?
Это логическое НЕ?

Answer (score 1):

Это побитовая операция "не".
Для целочисленных значений `~n` равно `-(n+1)`, так что получается `echo -6-5`
Подробнее: https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.bitwise.php